# Absolute path in RunApp

Tags: excel, ms-access

I took over an App that uses RunApp to open an Excel file. Unfortunately, the App was originally written to be used in a single PC. It is now on the network and needs to be accessed by several users who do not have Excel exactly on the location that is hard coded in the RunApp command. How do I write a "general" path to the local Excel copy of each user ?

Thank you.

/bernard

Comment: If I just run `start EXCEL.EXE` it opens. No additional path necessary. Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks, Brad, but no, it does not. The integrated macro only uses the command line :
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\excel.exe Z:\MyFile.xls" 
and when I try anything but the full path to excel it gives me the message "No record found". I suppose it looks for an Access table (??)

/bernard